# How to implement security context holder in node.js like spring does in java?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I know express has sessions , but it set the session in req object. Problem is you have to keep passing the req object in your functions in order to fetch security context object . I believe its hard to implement the spring way because node.js is single threaded and spring set the context object in thread level and thats why spring is able to provide isolated context objects for multiple concurrent requests.  Can anyone think a way to implement the same thing in node.js ?